# Can I still download Worklight Studio 5.06 after the release of 6.0, and how do I do it?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can I still download Worklight Studio 5.06 after the release of 6.0, and how do I do it from within Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

For the free Developer Edition, you can now download the previous release (5.0.6.x) as a zip file and install it in eclipse using the install archive option. Get the zip file here:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_update_site_wde.5.0.6.2.zip

Note: This version is not available on Eclipse Marketplace; only the latest IBM Worklight Developer Edition is ever available on Eclipse Marketplace.