# Downgrade Worklight 6 from Eclipse

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, uninstallation, downgrade

My eclipse recently updated to Worklight 6 and screwed all my projects .. Is there a way to downgrade to Worklight 5 ? Does anyone have a Worklight 5 installation zip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For the free Developer Edition, no, only the latest version is available.* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17285228/186909))

You will find information about buying IBM Worklight [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/worklight/).

I think it's worthwhile spending a bit of time making your project(s) Worklight 6.0 compatible. There are a lot of new features (JSONStore runs on the browser, better client-side logger, analytics, geolocation, etc) and overall improvements and fixes. I recommend you open another question and provide details about your environment, relevant pieces of code and log messages, what your goal is and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. Can you please tell me which edition of worklight allows for downgrade .. So that we can go ahead and order that from our manager ...

Comment: Or we could just help you fix your project... tell us what is not working.